# Down-casting vs. multiple fields

Tags: java, interface, downcast

I often read about that down-casting is a bad thing, and now that I need it, I ask myself what alternatives I have in my example:

I have an `Interface A`

Three Classes that implement Interface A: `X1, X2, X3`

These classes describe the same content, but in different "formats" and processes (simply put), which is why I had to divide them.

Now I have a class as follows:

`class Test {
  A obj;
}`

Depending on the "format", I do either `obj = new X1(), obj = new X2() or obj = new X2()`.

And from now on, I have to use a lot of down-casting within this class to access the classes methods, when working with the object (aside from the methods in A). The only alternative I see, is to make a field for every possible class, of which only one is ever used. Which seems bad as well.

Any suggestions on how a better design would look like?

Thank you for any help.

**EDIT:** This is my scenario (simply put):

My main class is a container for certain data. One of which is a content attribute (kinda like the body of a HTTP Request). The content can be:

- plain text (two seperate strings)
- file (just the file path, md5, etc.) -> Will be loaded into an input stream later on.
- unknown (bytes) -> I can't and I actually don't have to know. The context later on will give me information about it.

For every type, I created a Class (TextContent, FileContent, UnknownContent). They implement the Interface Content that has the method getBytes(), that will return the content as a byte array.

Usage of the content:

1. Creation

`ContainerClass.setContent(plainText)` -> `BaseInterface content = new TextContent(plainText)`
`ContainerClass.setFile(file)` -> `BaseInterface content = new FileContent(file)`
`ContainerClass.setContent(someBytes)` -> `BaseInterface content = new UnknownContent(someBytes)`

2. My Container object can be saved to a json. The content object will only be saved, if it is Text or File (therefor I can't implement a toJsonObject() in the interface).
3. When the content is text, I want to check it for certain patterns. I do that outside of the container class with a Matcher Class (e.g. `((TextContent)container.content).getText()` -> sadly, the FileContent has no single text it could return, so I can't implement that one either). I could add a getContentAs..() method to my container class that will cast it appropriately, but I feel like I just work around the underlying issue :(

Comment: `Test` should not _care_ whether `obj` is `X1` or `X2` - it should only _know_ or _care_ that `obj` _is an_ `A`! Even that fact that `Test` knows that there is a `X1` or `X2` is a **design mistake**. You need to investigate _why_ `Test` needs to know this to work out what is wrong with the design; but downcasting is a sign that the abstraction as at the wrong layer. E.g. if `Test` is constantly deciding on behaviour depending on the runtime type of `obj` then maybe a Visitor Pattern would be better.

Comment: If the processes are similar but have different implementations, why not declare an abstract method in the interface and have each class overrride the methods?

Comment: Could you post some example code? Maybe a (very) simplified situation in which you are downcasting?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thank you for your answer. I know I did a design mistake somewhere, but it is kinda hard for me to figure out how to resolve this. I updated my post to show my scenario. Maybe you have some thoughts on that. Thanks!

Comment: @jmw5598 Each type has some "unique" methods that they don't share with others. To access them, I need to down-cast.

Comment: Okay, I begin to see. But 1) why can't your `BinaryContent` simply turn itself into Base64 for saving into JSON (`content: aAbCx==` etc). 2) you can use `Scanner` to search for regex in a `Stream` with [`findWithinHorizon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findWithinHorizon-java.util.regex.Pattern-int-) negating any need to differentiate types of content. If all these are `Content` then they should behave as such, if not then you need to redesign your hierarchy.

Comment: Good point on both. Turning the BinaryContent into a Base64 via getText() was something I was thinking about, too. But I did not know about the posibility to search a stream for regex. That could solve a few problems. But what do you mean by "need to differentiate types of content". Is it better to put all that in just one class, or that I don't have to differentiate the type when I use them?

Answer (score -3):

Since the data is the same, it sounds like you only want one class here, not multiple.  Keep the formatting separate from the data.

Comment: Multiple classes are *fine*.

Comment: OO programming is about _behaviour_ as well as _data_. The whole point being that behaviour and data are stored together in a "class", with an `interface` exposing common **behaviour**. This answer makes little to no sense.